# Trying to install wordpress on docker for windows

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, docker

I am using docker for windows, I just installed it and I have the following `stack.yml` file which returns an error I will put below the `yml` file. I don't understand what may be causing the issue I am running the command `docker-compose -f stack.yml up` do get everything to work, could someone please help. Thanks ahead of time.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
```

error

```
wordpress_1  | Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The app needs to have the `db` run beforehand.
Add the `depends_on` value for the WordPress service, which will make sure the db is container is up, before the WordPress container.
The MySQL service within the container should boot up soon.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
```

Comment: I get the following error `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: it hangs with some other bugs as well

Comment: `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name ` - That is a warning.. Safe to skip - You can set the ServerName in the Apache config to fix this

Comment: `it hangs with some other bugs as well ` - what other bug are you referring to ? Could you please share more details about it?